# How to select elements of a column of which a corresponding columns contains elements that are in a given list?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I have a surprisingly tricky problem to solve in Google Sheets, which must be not too hard, but somehow I don't manage. It is a large sheet, but it boils down to the following:

Two Google Sheet columns:

```
Data 1  Data 2      
aa     2008             
bb     2008             
cc     2009             
dd     2010         
ee     2011         
ff     2012         
bb     2013         
gg     2014         
cc     2015         
hh     2016         
ii     2017
```

(Mark: there are re-occurring elements in column 1)

The problem: I have a sublist, a column containing  a bunch of elements, say: aa, bb, and cc

I want a filter to create a list with all the years which "contain" (at least) one of the elements in this list. In this example (using Unique) that would result in the list `[2008, 2009, 2013, 2015]`

I have tried Filter / Error / Match / Lookup / Vlookup, but I just cannot manage.

I have searched the fora a lot but cannot find this particular situation. 
Anyone an idea how to tackle this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2):

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,REGEXMATCH(A:A,TEXTJOIN("|",1,D:D))))`

[image]

`TEXTJOIN("|",1,D:D)` will create a regular expressions to check any match: `aa|bb|cc`.

Note: regular expressions are case sensitive: `aa` nor equals `Aa`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!!!!

It works, I already implemented it in the bigger multi-tab sheet.

This one has costed me a lot of time, even though I am quite experienced with this, but I would never have thought of this trick with TEXTJOIN.
Very creative, I am impressed, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

at some point you may need to get rid of case sensitivity and add more accuracy:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B, REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A:A), "^aa$|^bb$|^cc$")))
```

[image: 0]

or:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B, REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A:A), "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, D:D)&"$")))
```

Comment: or use case insensitive flag in RegEx: `(?i)camelcase`